# Template learning in Neural Network for control applicatication

Tags: neural-networks, control-theory

Are there any advantages to using a neural network to mimic the output of a control system (also known as template learning). Are there any functioning examples of this technique in real world applications.

Comment: You mean something like http://www.bizjournals.com/sanjose/news/2016/07/20/google-is-using-deepmind-artificial-intelligenceto.html ?

Comment: Well this is certainly an example of an ANN providing supervisory control to the cooling system of a data center. But there is no information on whether ANN was trained using input-output data from a previously existing controller/human expert.

Comment: Good point, they indeed didn't try to mimic the human expert, but improve on it. https://deepmind.com/blog gives a bit more details. They could have imitated it by changing the objective function.